# unable to sort using slickgrid + knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, slickgrid

I was able to create knockout model and load slikgrid with custom bindings. I was following this example in JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joybroto/bwSmy/4/

But I am not able to add sorting to the columns. By the slickgrid documentation I have to add `sortable: true` to columns. I did it.

Also documentation (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Getting-Started) says that sorting should be achieved by "by listening the onSort method":

```
slickgrid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args){ // args: sort information. 
        var field = args.sortCol.field;

        rows.sort(function(a, b){
            var result = 
                a[field] > b[field] ? 1 :
                a[field] < b[field] ? -1 :
                0;

            return args.sortAsc ? result : -result;
        });

        slickgrid.invalidate();         
    });
```

I do not understand for 100% how knockout custom bindings with slickgrid are done yet. So I am not able to understand how to subscribe onSort using knockout part.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I added the event subscription right in the init: part of the code, and through debugging I know it fires.  I can see also that many row pairs are compared and output 1 or -1, and then that the grid does invalidate.  But it shows back as it was initially. If you find the answer by yourself please post it here! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  You have to keep a reference to your data settings separately, and sort on them, instead of those inside the args parameter.

So here it goes, with the help of many good answers here ([Updating SlickGrid with Knockoutjs via dependentObservable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742821/updating-slickgrid-with-knockoutjs-via-dependentobservable)) and this (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example-multi-column-sort.html).  It's based on multi-column sort :

```
var grid;
var gridData;
ko.bindingHandlers.slickGrid = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var settings = valueAccessor();
        gridData = ko.toJS(settings.data); // instead of ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.data) since within my ObservableArray there are Observables.
        var columns = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.columns);
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.options) || {};
        grid = new Slick.Grid(element, gridData, columns, options);

        grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            var cols = args.sortCols;

            gridData.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
                for (var i = 0, l = cols.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
                    var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
                    var value1 = dataRow1[field], value2 = dataRow2[field];
                    var result = (value1 == value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
                    if (result != 0) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            });
            grid.invalidate();
    });
},
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, viewModel) {
        var settings = valueAccessor();
        gridData = ko.toJS(settings.data); //just for subscription
        grid.setData(gridData, false);
        grid.resizeCanvas(); // NB Very important for when a scrollbar appears
        grid.render();
    }

};
```

It's not 100% pretty, but it works.